# Is ARCore compatable with Android Instant Apps?

Tags: arcore, android-instant-apps

I heard ARCore support was announced for instant apps last year, but I haven't seen any around and can't find any documentation on the subject.

Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to find any documentation on Instant Apps support either...

But I refactored the sample [google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/samples/hellosceneform](http://google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hellosceneform) to support instant apps (*roughly following the guide @ [codelabs/android-instant-apps](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0); moving the core contents to a base module*), and I was able to run it as an instant app.

It ran fine on a Pixel 2 XL 8.1.0, but I didn't have any [AR-compatible](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) devices to confirm for N, but it should be a-ok too.

You can always report ARCore+InstantApps issues/bugs to [google/issuetracker/instant-apps](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/316045#basic).